# PyMongo and Flask on Linux server

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to connect to connect to my MongoDB instance from my FLASK app and I've run into an issue. I followed the tutorial at https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

When I try to run the server I get the following error:
`ImportError: No module named flask.ext.pymongo`

I've ran `pip install Flask-PyMongo`.
The code fails when I try to import PyMongo using `from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo`

Comment: did you name your file flask.py ?

Comment: @biobirdman which file do you mean?

Comment: Are you sure that pip is linked to the same interpreter you use to run your application? Is Flask-PyMongo listed under `python -m pip list`?

Comment: Turns out my Flask app only uses the libraries in the 'libs' folder. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution to the problem was that I needed to download Flask-PyMongo to my projects local libs folder using `pip install -t lib Flask-PyMongo`

This is due to the line in my config file `vendor.add('lib')`